# SQL first query very slow with Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I worked on two different projects using two differnt versions of Visual Studio (2010 and 2013) and two differents types of database (Oracle SQL and SQLServer).

In each case, if I used my sql client software to execute a simple query (SELECT * ...), I don't have any trouble, it is fast.

However, when I try to execute a query from Visual Studio (with Entity Framework or with ExecuteNonQuery method), it is very slow. And when I say slow, I mean 15 minutes at least. 
But this happen only with the first query I try to execute. When it's finally done, the following queries are executed quickly...

it's not a code issue, all works great on other computers (there is several developers on the two projects). And it's not a problem of number of data, I have the same problem if my tables are almost empty.

Did anyone already have this issue ? How can I solve it?

Comment: We need more information, code examples etc. Have you tried using `Database.Log` with the Entityframework to output the query it is acctually running and looked at it? Could it be entity-relationships that are causing the problem with EF-mapping?

Comment: Typically, IDEs like SQL Developer or Toad only load the first 500 rows (this is configurable).  In your code (you should post it), you're pulling ALL rows from the query through a loop (I suppose), which is probably why its taking so long.  But again, you need to post your code

Comment: Actually, it cannot be a code issue because all works great on other computers. And it's not a problem of number of data, I have the same problem if my tables are almost empty... (I will edit my post with these info)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250948/why-is-sql-server-object-explorer-in-visual-studio-so-slow)