# Why is SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio so slow?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database

I just created a new SQL Server Database in Azure and then opened it in Visual Studio 2015 using the link in the Azure Portal.  I had to add my IP to the firewall but otherwise the process went smoothly.

However, when I am trying to interact with the database server via SQL Server Object Explorer it is painfully slow.  Expanding any of the folders in my Database (e.g., `Tables` folder) takes 10 to 30 seconds.  The database is brand new, so the only things it has are whatever Azure creates when it instantiates a new DB.

This is the second Azure DB I have created and tried to view in Visual Studio and both have the same problem.  With the first one I thought maybe I did something wrong during setup but this time I made sure to do everything by the book.

Running actual queries against the DB from within Visual Studio (right click the DB, `New Query ...`, `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;`) is very fast, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with my connection to Azure.

Why is it so painfully slow?  What can I do to make it faster?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (`14.0.24720.00`) on Windows 10 (fully patched) and during database creation I checked the box to use the latest version.

Comment: Purely speculative, but the list of properties that gets fetched for the list of table is more than just the table names. That is, it likely pulls all of the columns and their data types, any indexes along with their definitions, constraints, etc. If you want to see everything that goes on, connect to an instance that you can run a trace on and trace it. Now imagine all of that traffic going across the internet. TL;DR - using a GUI over the internet is slow.

Comment: The explorer in Visual Studio does not appear to be grabbing all information.  If I expand the `Tables` folder for example I then have to expand each table separately.  Once expanded I have to expand `columns` subfolder as well.  This implies that all of the table data isn't being transmitted.  Also, with a brand new database the entire database could be transferred to my local machine in a second or two (100MBit internet).  Re: test locally, I am using Azure so I don't have to learn how to run MS SQL Server locally . ;)

Comment: Does the subsequent expansion of columns (for instance) take a lot of time or is it fast? Also, while it may be a small amount of data in aggregate, if it's a chat protocol, it's making a lot of round trips.

Comment: Every interaction is very slow.  Whether it is expanding the top level, or expanding a leaf node.

Comment: For me it's the same. Every interaction is eternal... It doesn't matter the size of the database or the schema. This tool is poorly implemented.

Comment: Still unusable. Crashes frequently too, when using and debugger is running.

Comment: This is still totally f***d and in 2020. Come on VS team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server Object Explorer (SSDT) in Visual Studio builds a schema model of entire database when you connect a database first time. This is a concept of model based database development which provides benefits such as validating scripts against database without needing to modify the live database etc. When it comes to Azure SQL DB where the resource is limited with your database's pricing tier, the performance of executing queries to fetch database model can vary. Based on our performance tests, pricing tiers above S1/S2 provides a similar interactivity as local or on-prem SQL instance.

More in details, current SSDT's mechanism is to composite minimum number of queries to minimize the number of round-trip operations with SQL server/database hence each query execution time is longer. It affects the interactivity of SQL Server Object Explorer while the query is being executed.

To enhance, SSDT team is revising the design for Azure SQLDB to provide a faster interaction experience while keeping the benefit of model based database development.

**Disclosure: I work on the SQL Data Tools team as a PM**

Comment: "`...when you connect a database first time...`"  I am experiencing slowness with every interaction, not just on initial load.  Is the model not cached and instead updated every time I interact with the DB?

Comment: More precisely, a model is built per VS session. If you close and restart VS then it starts the process over again for a live connection. If the model is built from a project, there is a saved cache. It's a difference between live connection vs project. Once the model is built, interactions become faster.

Comment: For snappier database schema browsing and simple schema discovery, tools like SSMS or Server Explorer in VS will be faster since those tools follow a different approach where they fetch a portion of schema information on demand based on your interaction so each transaction is much smaller and faster while it is chatty.

Comment: The initial loading of the schema of a S0 database with twenty empty tables takes more than 30 sec. But what's worse is that every single operation I do after that (unfolding the columns of a table or opening its design view) takes more than a minute... What's the point of the initial schema build then??? Sorry man, but something more goes wrong here...

Comment: @EricKang any update? This is still unusable and painful, SSMS is quite slow too...

Comment: @EricKang I have discovered this feature performs very poorly when using VS2017 + SQL2016 in AWS on a 20ms SLA connection due to high number of round trips. .

Comment: Update pls? VS with Azure SQL is like wading through thick blancmange on barbiturates

Comment: This is insanely slow. It also tends to hang Visual Studio randomly for more than a minute, or when refreshing a Data view for any table. Something HAS to be wrong!

Comment: Two years after and we're in the same point... What kind of professionals are working on this?

Comment: I have this problem with any query that may happen to investigate the information_schema in some manner. Can be multiple minutes and more.

Comment: It's painfully slow with localdb (.mdf file), I'm not even using Azure.

Comment: its almost the end of 2021 and this problem is still here, way to go vs SSDT team

Answer (score 1):

Good tip from @eric-kang in his comment to use 'Server Explorer' instead of 'SQL Server Object Explorer' - this is much better for basic data queries as its actually usable in real time

Comment: Worked immediately. But second attempt to drop a table from an Azure db just crashed VS. Still, better than that PoS object explorer.